# Wired network stops every day on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: networking, 19.04, wired

So I posted this under a similar post that was unresolved but was asked to start a new question.  So I am copying it over and posting it again..

I have the same issue happening. After upgrade to 19.04 about once a day I lose my network connection and only rebooting will bring it back. I am using a VPN and just got a new router, so it has been a bit more complicated for me to figure out. Only the upgrade to 19.04 and the router are new though.

Here is some of my networking output. The system is in a working state as I do this. I will try and copy again when it quits working next time.

```
$ sudo lshw -C network  
[sudo] password for xxxx:   
  *-network                   
       description: Ethernet interface  
       product: NetLink BCM57781 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe  
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries  
       physical id: 0  
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0  
       logical name: enp6s0  
       version: 10  
       serial: bc:5f:f4:2b:1b:e0  
       size: 1Gbit/s  
       capacity: 1Gbit/s  
       width: 64 bits  
       clock: 33MHz  
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation  
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3  driverversion=3.137 duplex=full firmware=sb latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s  
       resources: irq:17 memory:f0010000-f001ffff memory:f0000000-f000ffff memory:f7a00000-f7a007ff  
  *-network  
       description: Ethernet interface  
       physical id: 1  
       logical name: br0  
       serial: bc:5f:f4:2b:1b:e0  
       capabilities: ethernet physical  
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.xxx.xxx link=yes multicast=yes  

$ nmcli device  
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION   
br0     bridge    connected  br0          
tun0    tun       connected  tun0         
enp6s0  ethernet  connected  enp6s0       
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --   

$ ip addr show  
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000  
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00  
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo  
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever  
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host   
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever  
2: enp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000  
    link/ether bc:5f:f4:2b:1b:e0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  
3: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000  
    link/ether bc:5f:f4:2b:1b:e0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  
    inet 192.168.xxx.xxx/24 brd 192.168.xxx.255 scope global dynamic br0  
       valid_lft 68779sec preferred_lft 68779sec  
    inet6 fe80::be5f:f4ff:fe2b:1be0/64 scope link   
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever  
5: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100  
    link/none   
    inet 10.11.xx.x peer 10.11.xx.x/32 scope global tun0  
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever  
    inet6 fe80::d792:6378:2382:c501/64 scope link stable-privacy   
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever  

$ sudo lshw -short -class network  
H/W path                     Device      Class          Description  
===================================================================  
/0/100/1c.5/0                enp6s0      network        NetLink BCM57781 Gigabit  
/1                           br0         network        Ethernet interface  

$ networkctl status  
WARNING: systemd-networkd is not running, output will be incomplete.  

●        State: n/a  
       Address: 192.168.xxx.xxx on br0  
                10.11.xx.x on tun0  
                fe80::be5f:f4ff:fe2b:1be0 on br0  
                fe80::d792:6378:2382:c501 on tun0  
       Gateway: 192.168.xxx.1 (NETGEAR) on br0  

$ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 52 Jul 26 11:01 /etc/resolv.conf  

resolv.conf has the VPN services DNS servers listed in it. I've been using the same VPN service on this computer for years, so other than the upgrade to 19.04 nothing should have changed. I'm still not sure that my new router doesn't have something to do with it, but it isn't correlating to the rest of the network losing its internet. I am losing all networking on my PC, local and internet.

**I spent the time getting the output again with the networking in a failed state.**

$ sudo lshw -C network  
[sudo] password for scott:   
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface  
       product: NetLink BCM57781 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe  
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries  
       physical id: 0  
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0  
       logical name: enp6s0  
       version: 10  
       serial: bc:5f:f4:2b:1b:e0  
       size: 1Gbit/s  
       capacity: 1Gbit/s  
       width: 64 bits  
       clock: 33MHz  
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation  
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 duplex=full firmware=sb latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes  
 port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:17 memory:f0010000-f001ffff memory:f0000000-f000ffff memory:f7a00000-f7a007ff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: br0
       serial: bc:5f:f4:2b:1b:e0
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A link=yes multicast=yes

$ nmcli device  
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION   
br0     bridge    connected  br0          
enp6s0  ethernet  connected  enp6s0       
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --       



$ ip addr show  
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000  
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00  
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo  
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever  
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host   
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever  
2: enp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000  
    link/ether bc:5f:f4:2b:1b:e0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  
3: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000  
    link/ether bc:5f:f4:2b:1b:e0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  
    inet6 fe80::be5f:f4ff:fe2b:1be0/64 scope link   
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever  

$ sudo lshw -short -class network  
H/W path                     Device      Class          Description  
===================================================================  
/0/100/1c.5/0                enp6s0      network        NetLink BCM57781 Gigabit  
/1                           br0         network        Ethernet interface  

$ networkctl status  
WARNING: systemd-networkd is not running, output will be incomplete.  

●        State: n/a  
       Address: fe80::be5f:f4ff:fe2b:1be0 on br0  

 ls -l /etc/resolv.conf  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 52 Jul 27 11:00 /etc/resolv.conf  

 `cat /etc/resolv.conf  `
# Generated by NetworkManager  
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

**@heynnema** here is the output with the VPN up. I will post it with it down probably in the morning after it goes down again. It doesn't appear as if it is affecting the rest of the network. I have plugged directly into the router from  my workstation and into my dell PowerConnect 2816 switch. I thought I might be having a bad port or switch issue. But doesn't seem to make a difference.

`cat /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

`cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
# all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 192.168.xxx.1
```

`cat /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

Ok here is the system down versions of the resolv and resolved files

`cat /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

Nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

`cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
# all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

Nameserver 192.168.xxx.1
```

`cat /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96924/discussion-on-question-by-audeojude-wired-network-stops-every-day-on-ubuntu-19-0).